# Increasing the volume of a object in a photograph

Tags: optics, geometry, geometric-optics

I have two images which look like this ---

[image: Image 1]

[image]

These images are two views of a calibration object --- the white die that you see hanging in the middle.

The problem is that, the die is too small and is not working well for my study. Now instead of repeating filming, I was thinking about artificially increasing the size of the die using an image rendering software.

I thought about just select the border of the die in photoshop and stretching it out. But then there are two errors in that. First stretching is itself erroneous. And secondly, I cannot exactly change the other view just like the first view. So I dropped that idea.

Can you guys please suggest me a method using which I can increase the size of my die, and keeping the perspective all right? Any software I could use?

Comment: wrap it around a sphere, this is a geometrical solution (or use projective coordinates), still this should better be asked in a signal processing or image processing forum

Comment: When you say "too small" - does that mean not enough of the field of view is covered, or that you don't have enough resolution, or simply that the calibration software is looking for a larger object? If it is one of the first two, you can't fix it. If it is the third, you should just crop the image. Messing with data is unlikely to improve the quality of the calibration...

Comment: @Floris Not enough of the field of view is covered. Why can't I fix it?

Comment: You need calibration information about your field of view. You don't have that information. You can't make it "appear out of thin air". It's like saying you want to know the distance from New York to Chicago, but your tape measure will only go as far as Cleveland. You can stretch your tape measure to reach Chicago, but you still won't know how far it is...

Comment: No, now my unit will change, because of my stretched tape. And I can start working in this new unit.?